# How i can set the tags values of Text Views inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, tags, textview

I have a listview with multicolumns, where I have several textviews in each row. Including two textview in each row with `orientation="vertical"`.

In the xml file I can set the tag of each textview. However this tag of each textview is equal in each row.

How I can set the tag of each textview? The same problem happens with the id. In the first row it's ok. The problem is in following rows.

I put an image with an example.

[image]

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container,false);
    lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylistData =
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    String[] columnTags = new String[] {"hour","col1", "col2", "col3","col4", "col5", "col6","col7", "col8", "col9","col10", "col11", "col12","col13","col14"};

    int[] columnIds = new int[] {R.id.tv_list_item1,R.id.tv_listRow_item1, R.id.tv_listRow_item2, R.id.tv_listRow_item3,R.id.tv_listRow_item4, R.id.tv_listRow_item5, R.id.tv_listRow_item6,R.id.tv_listRow_item7, R.id.tv_listRow_item8, R.id.tv_listRow_item9,R.id.tv_listRow_item10, R.id.tv_listRow_item11, R.id.tv_listRow_item12,R.id.tv_listRow_item13, R.id.tv_listRow_item14};
    for(int i=0; i<24; i++)
    {
       HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int j=0; j<15; j++)
         {
      if(j==0){
    map.put("hour", "0"+i+":00");
    if(i<10){
        map.put("hour", "0"+i+":00");   
    }
    else
        map.put("hour", i+":00");
}
else if(j>0){
    map.put(columnTags[j], "row”+i+”col"+j);
}
   }
   mylistData.add(map);
   }
    SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter =
        new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylistData, R.layout.sechedule_list_row,
                      columnTags , columnIds);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Have you considered TableLayout?

Comment: As mentioned by wtsang02, I also recommend you use a TableLayout for this problem. But if you still want to use the current code that is fine by me. But then you should consider adding some code you are using now that is giving you problems. That will help us in determining what is wrong

Comment: I put some code where i populate the listview. My intention is contruct a calendar schedule with 24 rows (1 row for each hour) and 7 columns (1 column for each day of week). But i need textview with different tags but don't konw gow....

Comment: Wtsang02 and ndsmyter, thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Reconsider using of hashmap. Because HashMap can hold only unique keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own custom adapter and then in getView set your tags and ids for each text view.

Here is an example how to use getView
[android - custom ListView, getView method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539356/android-custom-listview-getview-method)

Answer (score 0):

This one example help you lot i think http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/